# Konfirmandenblase vs. Konfirmantenblase

Tags: spelling, suffix

Heute hat YouFM auf Facebook ein [Bild](https://www.facebook.com/youfm/photos/a.329221542175.190443.256073677175/10153816434232176/?type=3) in Umlauf gebracht, das das Wort

> Konfirmantenblase

enthielt.

Ich war immer der Überzeugung, da es vom Wort [Konfirmand](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Konfirmand) abgeleitet ist, müsse es mit *d* geschrieben werden, also

> Konfirmandenblase.<sup>*</sup>

**Ist meine Annahme richtig, ist die Schreibweise mit *d* korrekt?**

Ein kurzer [Googlefight](http://www.googlefight.com/konfirmandenblase-vs-konfirmantenblase.php) zeigt allerdings, dass die Schreibweise mit *t* gar nicht so unüblich ist. Zugegebenermaßen ist das keine wirklich verlässliche Methode so etwas zu ermitteln.
Auf duden.de habe ich zumindest im Deutsch-Englisch Wörterbuch einen Eintrag für [Konfirmandenblase](http://www.duden.de/woerterbuch/deutsch-englisch/Konfirmandenblase) gefunden. Die alternative Schreibung allerdings nicht. Wiktionary.de führt keine der beiden Schreibungen, verweist jedoch in ihrem Eintrag zu [Blase](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Blase) auf die Schreibung mit *d*.
Auch konnte ich generell keine Verweise zwischen diesen Schreibungen finden, im Sinne von *auch geläufig: ~* oder *häufig auch: ~*.

**Welchen Ursprung hat die Schreibung mit *t* und ist sie korrekt?**

---

**Fußnote**
Ein Synonym für Konfirmandenblase ist auch Sextanerblase oder Pionierblase. Man benutzt es häufig umgangssprachlich für Personen, die in kurzen Abständen zur Toilette gehen müssen, vor Allem als *„Du hast ja eine ~“*.
Es gibt mehrere Varianten die Herkunft zu deuten, eine davon ist, dass man während des langweiligen (Konfirmanden-)Unterrichts häufiger als notwendig eine Toilettenpause angemeldet hat.
*Wissen macht Ah!* hat die Herkunft auf freundliche Art und Weise zusammengefasst in der Folge *[Ralf im Himmel](http://www.wdr.de/tv/wissenmachtah/sendungen/13_11.php5)* (ab ca. Minute 20:00).

Comment: Ich kannte das Wort nicht. Das liegt vermutlich daran, dass Österreich eher katholisch ist, die Konfirmation aber ein protestantischer Brauch ist. Katholiken werden stattdessen gefirmt. Das geschieht bei der Firmung und die zu firmende Person ist der Firmling. Zur Vorbereitung gibt es einen Firmunterricht. Soweit stimmt alles überein, aber ich habe nicht nur noch nie von einer Konfirmandenblase gehört, sondern auch noch nie von einer Firmlingsblase. Stattdessen kenne ich für Hochfrequenzpinkler die Sprüche »Hast du heute die kleine Blase mit?« und »Nimm das nächste Mal die große Blase mit«.

Comment: Auch ich als Lutheraner in Bayern (ja, das gibts) hab das Wort noch nie vorher gehört. Ich hätte es mir auch nicht erschließen können. A bleder Spruch wär mir scho eingefallen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Die Schreibweise mit *d* ist richtig. Die falsche Variante mit *t* kommt vermutlich daher, dass Personen, die das Wort *Konfirmand* nicht kennen, aufgrund des Klanges eine Ähnlichkeit zu Personenbezeichnungen auf *-ant* wie *Demonstrant* oder *Repräsentant* vermuten.

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe-F/ant.html) hat dazu eine schöne Erklärung:

> Mit *ant* gebildete Ableitungen bezeichnen in der Regel eine Person (oder Sache), die die Verbhandlung ausführt. Im Gegensatz dazu bildet das Suffix [*and*](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe-F/and.html) Bezeichnungen für eine Person oder Sache, die von der Verbhandlung betroffen werden soll.

Das passt ganz wunderbar, denn ein *Konfirmand* ist jemand, der *konfirmiert wird*, also von der Handlung des *Konfirmierens* betroffen ist. Diese Handlung umfasst den Segen durch den Pfarrer im Konfirmationsgottesdienst, aber auch eine vorgehende ein- bis zweijährige Unterweisung im Konfirmandenunterricht. Ein bisschen ausführlicher ist diese [Erklärung auf den Seiten der EKD](https://www.ekd.de/Konfirmation-11035.htm). Dass zur Konfirmation auch eine aktive Handlung der Konfirmanden, nämlich ihr Bekenntnis zur Taufe und zum Glauben, gehört, ändert an dieser sprachlichen Einordnung als "Betroffene" nichts.

Comment: vgl. beispielsweise auch [Informant](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Informant) (eine Person, die Informationen liefert) und [Informand](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Informand) (eine Person, die informiert wird)

Comment: Richtig. Der Konfirmant (= Pfarrer) konfirmiert den Konfirmanden. Da ein spezielles Wort für einen die Konfirmation ausführenden Pfarrer höchst überflüssig ist, existiert *Konfirmant* aber ausschließlich als Rechtschreibfehler.

Comment: @HansAdler: a) Bei Katholiken leitet der Bischof, nicht ein Pfarrer, die Zeremonie. Ist es bei Protestanten wirklich der Pfarrer und kein Bischof? b) Confirm heißt ja Bestätigen. Bestätigt nicht der Konfirmant seine Taufe durch die Konfirmation? Bestätigt der Bischof/Pfarrer die Taufe/Zugehörigkeit zur Gemeinde? So schlüssig finde ich die Herleitung jedenfalls nicht.

Comment: Das macht normalerweise der Gemeindepfarrer. Anders als die katholische Firmung ist es kein Sakrament. -- Die alternative Herleitung als der zu Bestätigende ist sehr gut und erklärt auch die Verwirrung. Allerdings stammt das Wort wohl tatsächlich von *confirmandus* (zu Bestätigender). Ich würde mal raten, dass schon beim lateinischen Begriff nicht ganz klar war, wer eigentlich was bestätigt.

Comment: @userunknown a) Die sächsische Landeskirche hat z.B. 765 Gemeinden und 1 Bischof - der hätte da viel zu tun. Andere ev. Landeskirchen haben gar keinen Bischof, [sondern z.B. einen Präses](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landesbischof). b) [Diese Erklärung der EKD](http://www.ekd.de/glauben/abc/konfirmation.html) leitet den Begriff von _Confirmatio_ = Bekräftigung, Stärkung ab. Die Konfirmation ist nicht nur ein Bekenntnis des Konfirmanden zur Taufe, sondern beinhaltet auch eine Unterweisung im Glauben, und natürlich den Segen. Insofern ist der Konfirmand auch ein Empfangender.

Comment: _Confirm_ (englisch) heißt zwar _bestätigen_, _confirmare_ (Latein) aber nicht (nur). Die relevante Bedeutung ist eher _bestärken_, _ermutigen_.